# Issue Generating GLOBAL_ANALYSIS_TOKEN via SonarQube API - 'name' Parameter Missing

Tags: sonarqube, token, sonarqube-api

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to generate a `GLOBAL_ANALYSIS_TOKEN` using the SonarQube API. I'd appreciate any assistance or insights you can offer.

#### Setup and Configuration

- **SonarQube Version:** Enterprise Edition Version 9.9.1 (build 69595)
- **Endpoint:** `https://quality-analysis.my-company.io/sonar/api/user_tokens/generate`
- **HTTP Method:** POST

#### Request Payload

Here is the JSON payload I am sending:

```json
{
    "name": "TestingfromAPI",
    "login": "ghassen@my-company.io",
    "projectKey": "demo",
    "type": "GLOBAL_ANALYSIS_TOKEN",
    "expirationDate": "2023-10-30"
}
```

#### Error Message

Upon sending the request, I receive the following error message:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "msg": "The 'name' parameter is missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Questions

1. Despite specifying the name parameter in the JSON payload, why am I still getting an error stating it's missing?
2. Is there any specific formatting or encoding required for the name parameter?
3. Could there be any version-specific limitations causing this?

Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation says nothing about content type for sending parameters. I assume they do not support JSON as an input.
You may try 'x-www-form-urlencoded' form instead.

```
curl  -u user:password --data 'name=dummy_token_name&type=GLOBAL_ANALYSIS_TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' http://localhost:9000/api/user_tokens/generate
```